# How do I transcode audio to a lower bitrate while passing through the video with ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have video lectures that use really high bitrates for audio, but would work fine as 32 bit mono.  Is there a way to transcode only the audio to a lower bit rate (32 bit mono from 161 kbps stereo) while leaving the video untouched?

Comment: You mean 32 kBit/s? Or 32 Bit sample size?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion 32 kB/s bit rate, sample at 48 khz, mono.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stream copy the video and downmix & re-encode the audio:

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v copy -b:a 32k -ac 1 output
```